# How do I uppercase a substring?

Tags: liquid

As an example, how do I check if a string contains "html"? If it does, uppercase that substring.

```
string = "html template"
{% if string contains 'html' %}{{ string | upcase }}{% endif %}
```

The above code makes the entire string uppercase, but I only want to uppercase "html".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using [`replace`](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers#standard-filters) instead of `upcase`:

```
string = "html template"
{{ string | replace: 'html','HTML'}}
```

*Note*: A filter applies on its parameter (here, `string`), that's why the `upcase` filter made your whole string uppercase.

Comment: I found this solution and I was posting it, but you did it faster, I have another problem. I want to specify more that just "html". for example "html, psd". How about that?

Comment: I found it, we can use multiple replace like {{ string | replace: 'html','HTML' | replace: 'css', 'CSS'}}

Comment: Indeed, you'll need to use multiple filters back to back. From [the source code](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/v2.6.0.rc1/lib/liquid/standardfilters.rb#L115-L118), it doesn't look like there is a way to do it using only one filter.